# Can I load data with Entity Framework using pre-defined sql view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to load data using a sql-view in Entity Framework 4.3.1? Using Code-First

Comment: Yes. Did you want to know anything more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you work with existing database where a view is already defined you can simply cheat EF and let it assume that the view is actually a table by using either `[Table("my_View")]` annotation on entity class or `.ToTable("my_View")` method in fluent mapping.